# Using string as a comparator - Python

Tags: python, comparator

I would like to use a string, such as "==" or ">" as a comparator for an if statement. For example:

```
comparator = ">="

if y comparator x:
    print("hello world")
```

I want to get

```
if y >= x:
    print("hello world")
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at the builtin `operator` module.

Answer (score 0):

You could use eval to convert strings into code:

```
comparator = ">="
if eval(f"{x}{comparator}{y}"):
    print("hello world")
```